# Python referencing old OpenSSL version on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

I'm running into an extremely frustrating issue due to the fact that my python keeps referencing an old openSSL version.

**This is what i did:**

- Installed the most recent OpenSSL version and added it to PATH
- Uninstalled my python and reinstalled it back in order to make it compile with the newer version
- Also tried to install a version of py I've never installed before

  Basically what I'm getting when printing my openSSL version is the following:

```
C:\Users\Nicholas>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

What I get on python instead:

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018'
>>>
```

If I do this on the other python version, it references to a even different and older OpenSSL version (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017). 
The only things that come to my mind is that uninstalling Py is not enough in order to make it reference  the new openssl version or that the new openSSL version is not installed properly. 
Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you purposefully install `Python 3.6.8` when you reinstalled it?

Comment: The reason for my question above, is that I haven't installed anything related to openSSL, and run `Python 3.7.4`. When I issue `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` I get `'OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019'`because that's what's been bundled inside of my installation of Python.

Comment: I would need to get this working on Py36, but the .8 version was a random decision

Comment: It's not really clear with how the question is formed right now that it's a requirement that you stay on an older version.

Comment: It is because it looks like different Python versions load different Cipher Suites. More specifically i need this cipher (DES-CBC3-SHA) to be loaded. I would like to investigate more to check if it was just removed with OpenSSL 1.1 or it depends on the python version too

Comment: `DES-CBC3-SHA` Is not a safe cipher anymore. If you have an application that ONLY talks with that cipher, then you have a whole other problem on your hands. However, if you're working on a new application then I highly recommend that you just use newer and better suites.